# How can I redirect to another page after submit button pressed?

Tags: php, mysql

Redirecting is not working, after I pressed my submit button.

```
<?php    
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
$id = $_POST['id'];
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "DELETE FROM data  WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
Database::disconnect();
header("Location: index.php");
} 
?>

<button type="submit">delete</button>
```

This is strange, because it actually worked on another page I made. Instead my page is just getting refreshed...

Comment: maybe you are on the same `index.php` file??

Comment: assuming you have a form and its posting to that if block successfully, then that should work `header("Location: index.php");` - redirects to the `index.php`. Any errors when you try ?

Comment: Did you specify `action` attribute of your form correctly? Do you know if you post to this code at all? Also good practice is to put `exit();` after your redirect.

Comment: are you getting an error message? Have you checked log files? It could be that you have output before the `header` statement, which would prevent redirecting.

Comment: Hello, my code was totally fine, but at the beginning of the page I did something wrong, so the redirecting did not work. I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was at the beginning of the page.

I wrote:

```
require('header.php');
require('database_connection.php');
```

But it needed to be:

```
require('database_connection.php');  
require('header.php');
```

I do not know what exactly this has to do with redirecting, but my code is working now!